# Twig: Use "Ignore Missing" on Include by default

Tags: php, twig

With Twig I am using [`{% include %}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) a lot. I need to attach `ignore missing` to every include, since I do not want to run into an Exception when a file is not found. This bloats the template code a lot and I am looking for an option to attach `ignore default` to all includes by default without repeating it with every include call. I am looking for an equivalent of [php's include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in Twig since Twig's own include behaves like php's require.

How can I include templates in Twig without having Exceptions thrown when a file is not found and without adding `ignore missing` to every single include?
I was looking for a config in Twig but did not find an option.

Comment: Seems bad practise to me though, to do this you would need to modify the twig env or twig template to your own. Why do you need to check every time?

Answer (score 2):

by over-riding built-in include

```
     class TokenParser_Include extends Twig_TokenParser
        {
            public function parse(Twig_Token $token)
            {
                $expr = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();

                list($variables, $only, $ignoreMissing) = $this->parseArguments();

                return new Twig_Node_Include($expr, $variables, $only, $ignoreMissing = true, $token->getLine(), $this->getTag());
            }

            protected function parseArguments()
            {
                $stream = $this->parser->getStream();

                $ignoreMissing = false;
                if ($stream->nextIf(Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'ignore')) {
                    $stream->expect(Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'missing');

                    $ignoreMissing = true;
                }

                $variables = null;
                if ($stream->nextIf(Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'with')) {
                    $variables = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
                }

                $only = false;
                if ($stream->nextIf(Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'only')) {
                    $only = true;
                }

                $stream->expect(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

                return array($variables, $only, $ignoreMissing);
            }

            public function getTag()
            {
                return 'include';
            }
        }

   $twig->addTokenParser(new TokenParser_Include());
```